# Auto-complete or auto-suggest from stored data in database

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, mysql

I developing plugin MLM.So i want all user name as suggestion in parent-name input form.
So how can i code it?
Which jquery included?
I add this code following

```
$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : FALSE;
if ($query) {
// escape values passed to db to avoid sql-injection
$depts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_mlm_info WHERE user_name LIKE '".$query."%' ORDER BY user_id ASC" );

$suggestions = array();
$data = array();
foreach($depts as $row) {
    $suggestions[] = $row->user_name;
    $data[] = $row->user_id;
}
$response = array(
    'query' => $query,
    'suggestions' => $suggestions,
    'data' => $data,
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Adding following jquery

```
wp_enqueue_script('newscript',plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.10.2.js' , __FILE__ ),array( 'jquery' )); 
wp_enqueue_script('newscript',plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui.js' , __FILE__ ),array( 'jquery' )); 
wp_enqueue_script('newscript',plugins_url( 'js/jquery.min.js' , __FILE__ ),array( 'jquery' )); 
wp_enqueue_script('newscript',plugins_url( 'https://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/local/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js/' , __FILE__ ),array( 'jquery' ));
```

but not working autosearch or auto suggestion field.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parent_name').autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:'/',
        // callback function:
        onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
});


});
```

Can you please help me for this problem?

Comment: Do you have any php errors or javascript errors?

Comment: No..actually i don't know i included files are working or not.(jquery)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're not quite enqueuing the scripts correctly.

The first argument should be a unique name for that script (not all 'newscript').
Also, you're enqueuing jquery twice.
I'm not certain where you're storing your files, but at least the last path is incorrect.
Finally, the third argument is to let WordPress know if the script that you're enqueuing is dependent on another script. jQuery UI and jQuery Autocomplete are dependent on jQuery, so you have those ones correct. The others are not needed.

In addition, WordPress already has jQuery, so you don't need to enqueue another copy of it.

This should get you a little closer anyway:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); //Because it ships with WordPress
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery-ui.js',array( 'jquery' )); 
wp_enqueue_script('autocomplete', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.26/jquery.autocomplete.js',array( 'jquery' ));
```

WordPress also ships with parts of jQuery UI and other helpful scripts. You can see the whole list and how to enqueue them here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/